# In the Set of Extended Complex Numbers, 3/0 = infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

There's something I don't quite understand about the extended set of complex numbers. Usually, a number

$\frac a 0 , a \in R$

is undefined. However, in the set of extended complex numbers,

$\frac a 0 = \infty $

Why/how is this possible?

Comment: The title question should say a/0, not 3/0.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is because it is defined that way.  We can make any definitions we want as long as we can show that they don't lead to contradictions.

A perhaps more useful answer is to look at a model that validates the equation. (This, incidentally, is also a way to show the definition is not self-contradictory.)  The model of the extended complex numbers is the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere).  In particular, the perspective as the complex projective line is probably most useful.

A point on the complex projective line is a pair of complex numbers $(z,w) \neq (0,0)$ which we consider equivalent to any point $(\lambda z, \lambda w)$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$.  This is very similar to rational numbers: just replace "complex" with "integer" and require that $w$ never be $0$.  If we think of $(z,w)$ as being like a formal $\frac{z}{w}$, it is easy to define all the arithmetic operations and show that they are well defined (i.e. preserve the notion of equality).  For our purposes, we only need reciprocation and that has the straightforward definition $(z,w)^{-1} = (w,z)$.

Now for all pairs $(z,w)$ where $w \neq 0$ we can represent the equivalence class containing that point by the representative $(r,1)$ which gives a one-to-one correspondence with the complex plane.  When $w = 0$ we have a single equivalence class which we call $\infty$ and typically represent by $(1,0)$ but is equivalent to all $(\lambda,0)$ for $\lambda \neq 0$.

As a final note, $\infty/\infty = (1,0)/(1,0) = (0,0)$ which is not a point on the complex projective line and so is undefined, but this means $\infty$ has no multiplicative inverse and thus the extended complex numbers don't form a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: They actually don't even form a ring since $\infty$ also has no additive inverse.